# Are AWS Lightsail and EC2 G3 compatible for exporting image?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, httprequest, amazon-ami, amazon-lightsail

I exported a Lightsail image to EC2 g2.2xlarge and g2.8xlarge and it worked without issue but after trying same on a g3.8xlarge instance, it isn't accessible from outside. I'm using another Lightsail image to use as main host and EC2 instance as a compute server. When I log the `on("error",callback)` output of http request, it says

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::ffff:x.y.z.w:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::ffff:x.y.z.w',
  port: 80 }
```

What I tried to solve:

- Disabling any Apache Tomcat: it says already disabled (I guess from image export)
- Prerouting from 80 to 1024(Nodejs app listens to it)
- Waiting for EC2 instance's status to become 2/2 checked (using aws sdk over javascript) before attempting to make any http request.
- Attach a security group which lets both 1024 and 80 ports and set to anywhere (not production, just testing) on both inbound and outbound rules.
- SSH connection works, I can install applications from SSH channel then for automation, I take its "image" and terminate instance and main server creates new instances from this image.(g2 instances no problem). Physically no problem but something stops HTTP requests.

I do these steps to move a Nodejs service to application:

- develop some module in Nodejs
- take snapshot
- export snapshot to ec2 (wait until it completes)
- open ec2 console, select exported AMI
- click launch (select g2 instance, security group, .., generate keys, login with ssh)
- install necessary software (to use resources of g2,p2,.. instances)
- get new image of complete installed environment (with detaching ssh to ensure no data is lost by doing this)
- use its AMI code in AWS SDK (Javascript) to create a new instance, wait for its running, wait for its both statuses be checked, run application.
- g2 image to create g2 instance, g3 image to create g3 instance.

But only works for g2 instances.

What else do I have to try? Why is this working fine on g2 instances but not on g3 instances?

- Ubuntu 18.04 (started with plain Ubuntu but its still called Amazon Ubuntu?)
- Nodejs 8 (running on 1024 port)
  --- Lightsail host uses expressjs for handling incoming requests, uses http for doing outgoing requests. Same for EC2 instance.

If this helps:

- EC2 instance can do http request to Lightsail instance.
- Lightsail instance can get this by express.js listening.
- At the first http request that Lightsail does to EC2 causes above error output. (g3 instance)
- On lightsail + g2 instance, both http requests and expressjs listening works on both servers.
- EC2 instances were shared, not dedicated.
- For requests, I use POST of HTTP and give it json object.

Perhaps http requesting + expressjs listening design is wrong too?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by toggling source-destination-check option from console before other server tried to do POST operation on it.

Default value was true and this was causing the "issue"(I thought there was a bug but it seems its a feature that I missed).